# why does the .on function give an error: TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

### I tried the .on function as well but I can't seem to get it fixed. It gives me an error: TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement.

```
    $(document).ready(function (e) 
     {

        $("#upload_button").click(function(){
          console.log("Clicked")
        $.ajax({
                 url: 'http://192.168.1.126/JTV/upload/myfile.php',
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: {'assetid':assetid, 'imgurl':imgurl, 'mname':mname, 
                 'videourl':videourl},
                 success: function(data)
                 {
                         console.log(data)
                 }
               });
             });
           });
```

And here is the HTML on AJAX load

```
   function my_function(assetID,mname,imgurl,videourl)
   {
       $("#video_response").empty();
       //alert("assetID:"+assetID+"\nMOvie name: "+mname+"\nImg 
        url:"+imgurl+"\nvideoURL:"+videourl)
        element = "";
        element += '<div align="center" style="padding-top:20px"><form>
        <label for="mname">Video Name</label>&nbsp&nbsp<input type="text" 
         name="mname" id="mname" placeholder="'+mname+'" style="color:black; 
        width: 300px; height: 30px; padding-left:5px">'
        element += '<br><br><br><label for="imgurl">Image - URL 
        </label>&nbsp&nbsp<input type="text" name="imgurl" id="imgurl" 
         value="'+imgurl+'" style="color:black; width: 300px; height: 30px; 
         padding-left:5px">'
         element += '<input type="hidden" name="imgurl" id="imgurl" 
         Value="'+assetID+'"  style="color:black; width: 300px; height: 
         30px; padding-left:5px">'
         element += '<br><br><input type="button" id="edit_btn" 
         style="background:orange; color:white;height:30px;" value="Save 
          Changes"></form></div><div align="center" id="update_err"></div>';
         $("#response").html( element );
     }
```

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '#upload_button', function(){ ... })`...use event delegation.

Comment: I am getting this error-
TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement.